# How to get sum of embedded collection in mongodb aggregation?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation

I have some issues working with mongodb aggregations.  This is the data collection,

```
{
 "subject":"maths",
 "year" : "2018"
 "marks" : [
   {
    "stuId" : "0001",
    "mark" : "90"
   },
   {
    "stuId" : "0002",
    "mark" : "56"
   }
 ]
}
{
 "subject":"science",
 "year" : "2018"
 "marks" : [
   {
    "stuId" : "0001",
    "mark" : "50"
   },
   {
    "stuId" : "0002",
    "mark" : "65"
   }
 ]
}
```

I want to calculate sum of the marks of each student and take the average of the each like below,

```
//sum of maths and science subjects

{ "year" : "2018", "stuId" : "0001", "sum": "140"},
{ "year" : "2018",  "stuId" : "0002",  "sum": "121"}
```

I have tried this code. No any result.

```
 mark.aggregate([
        {
            $match: {
                "year": year
            },
        },
        { $unwind: "$marks" },
        {
            $group: {
                "id": "$marks.stuId", "Total": { $sum: "$marks.mark" }
            }
        }
    ],
        function (err, results) {

            res.send(results)
            console.log(results)
        }
    );
```

Comment: Clarity:  You want sum of marks and avg of marks for all students by year?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: @AlexBlex I have tried this code. (Question updated)

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti Yes.

Comment: Ah -- so you do not need to agg by year.   Year is a FILTER.   You only need results for that one year?

Comment: You have no results because of the error. If you check "err" in the call back it should say something about missing _id in the $group stage. I believe you wanted to write `$group: {"_id":.....}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it, assuming you can grok that `_id` is the `stuId` post-group.
BTW, I would highly suggest modifying your data design so that `year` is an actual `datetime` type and `mark` is an integer.   Carrying these around as strings makes everything down the road that much harder.

```
var inp = "2018";

c = db.foo.aggregate([
{$match: {"year": inp}}

,{$unwind: "$marks"}

,{$group: {_id: "$marks.stuId",
           sum: {$sum: {$toInt: "$marks.mark"} },
           avg: {$avg: {$toInt: "$marks.mark"} }
    }}

]);
```

Comment: @SachinMuthumala w.r.t the sample dataset you provided this query runs fine, please [have a look](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vmXEq3FjqqW), I am guessing the filter on year that you are providing is a `numeric` where as in the dataset its `string`.